# Event binding clicks with backbone.js & jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, backbone-events

I need to bind two events in my `backbone.js`-view in order to toggle a menu. The idea is that if a button with the id `#toggler` is clicked the menu appears and any click outside the `#menu` element will hide the menu.

Unfortunately I cannot get this working with backbone's event binding without having the `outsideMenuHandler()` called on every click regardless if I clicked on the `#menu` element, or not.

What should I change to make this work?

**This is what I have done in backbone.js, which doesn't work as intended:**

```
myView = Backbone.View.extend({

    events: {
        'click #menu': 'insideMenuHandler',
        'click':       'outsideMenuHandler'
    }

    insideMenuHandler: function(e) {}, // Called when clicking #menu
    outsideMenuHandler: function(e) {} // Called on every click both on and off #menu

}
```

**Just as a reference, here's what I would do using jQuery alone:**

```
$(document).click(function(event) {
    if ( $(event.target).closest('#menu').get(0) == null ) {
        $("#menu").slideUp();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There are a couple things you need to sort out.

First of all, if your `insideMenuHandler` returns `false` or calls `e.stopPropogation()` then your `outsideMenuHandler` won't get called for clicks on `#menu`. For example:

> http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/8GjdS/

But that's not your whole problem. Your `outsideMenuHandler` will only be called for clicks on your view; so, if someone clicks on the page outside your view, your `outsideMenuHandler` won't get called and your menu won't go down. If you want the menu to go down when someone clicks anywhere outside `#menu`, then you'll have to manually bind to `body` and manually unbind when your view is destroyed. Something like this:

```
var myView = Backbone.View.extend({
    events: {
        'click #menu': 'insideMenuHandler'
    },

    initialize: function() {
        _.bindAll(this, 'insideMenuHandler', 'outsideMenuHandler');
    },

    render: function() {
        // Both <body> and <html> for paranoia.
        $('body, html').on('click', this.outsideMenuHandler);
        // ...
        return this;
    },

    remove: function() {
        // Clean up after ourselves.
        $('body, html').off('click', this.outsideMenuHandler);
        // ...
    },

    // ...
    outsideMenuHandler: function(e) {
        // ...
        return false;
    }
});
```

and then be sure to properly remove your view. For example:

> http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/MgkWG/1/

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. Very appreciated!  A quick question - as I understand, letting a click event return `false` will prevent any "default event" from occurring, meaning that all other clicks will be disabled as the `outsideMenuHandler` returns `false`. Am I getting myself into trouble if I let my `outsideMenuHandler` return `true` after performing my logic (hiding my menu)?

Comment: @Industrial: You'll end up with double calls to `outsideMenuHandler` from the `body, html` binding but that might not be a problem. You could probably get away with only binding `outsideMenuHandler` to `html` but you'd want to browser check that to make sure it behaves properly in all the browsers you care about.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is, that you bind your event to the DOM element that you define as the views el. So if this is not the `window.document` as in your jquery example you cant notice any click outside them. The easiest way in your example would be to add the events manually with jquery and not with backbone.